# Why in struts2 MVC is no direct link between the model and the view

Tags: model-view-controller, struts2

I am starting with the Struts2 framework, so I am trying to get more knowledge about this framework.

First thing I did was learn something about that framework. So I read about **[Key Technologies Primer](https://struts.apache.org/primer.html#mvc)** and there is one sentence that I don't understand.

The sentence (Section MVC):

> ...But, a direct link between the Model and the View is not practical for web applications...

Can you please explain this to me, Why that is not practical for web applications?

Thanks for your help all :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27204535/573032

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the paragraph above that one.

View/model interactions need to update server state, and the view layer is "split" in Java web apps (as opposed to Smalltalk MVC).

This design decision is no longer as relevant as it once was, but in the old Java web app world where action-based web apps were the norm, it made more sense.

Now that more web apps are client-side apps consuming server-side APIs this is a less-important consideration, but then you're no longer using the default (e.g., JSP) view layer of S2, rather you're using JSON as the view, and model/view interactions are handled on the client side through the server-side API.